# In NextJS 13, how can I dynamically update data in a server-side rendered component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

As a first-time user of NextJS 13, I am following their App directory structure. I have implemented a server-side rendered component that retrieves categories from my database using Prisma and displays them as a list on the page. Additionally, I have a client-side component that includes an "Add" button, which triggers a modal with a textbox and a "Submit" button to create a new category in the database.

Now, here's where I'm encountering an issue. Since the client-side component relies on state management with UseState, it cannot directly access Prisma to create a new category on the server. Firstly, what is the preferred method for doing this? Should I define a new API route and POST data directly from the client component?

Secondly, and my main question, how can I dynamically display the newly posted data in the server-side component without requiring a full page refresh? In particular, is there a way to seamlessly add the new category to the existing list without reloading the entire page?

Answer (score 1):

At least as of now, it is not possible to update state of the Server Component similar to how you update state on the client side. For using prisma, you should define route handler. Recommended path would be `/api/route.ts` in the same directory that serves your page. Or, if you choose, you can also use `pages/api` for your REST API routes.

Comment: In this case, to have it displayed dynamically, I would need to do the fetch and post all in a client component?

Comment: Consider moving your list to client side.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve what you need by using server actions, and calling `revalidatePath` at the end of your action.

Server actions is an experimental feature at the moment, so it needs to be activated in your `next.config.js` file:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    serverActions: true,
  },
};
```

Now imaging you have the following file structure:

```
/app
  categories/
    actions.ts
    AddCategoryForm.tsx
    page.tsx
```

Your `page.tsx` is a server component which could look like this:

```js
import { PrismaClient, Category } from "@prisma/client";
import AddCategoryForm from "./AddCategoryForm";

async function getCategories() {
  try {
    const prisma: PrismaClient = new PrismaClient();
    const categories: Category[] = await prisma.category.findMany();
    return categories;
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error.message ?? 'Could not fetch the categories');
  }
}

export default async function CategoriesPage() {
  const categories: Category[] = await getCategories();

  return (
    <div>
      <AddCategoryForm />
      
      <ul>
        {categories.map((category) => (
          <li key={category.id}>{category.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What it does essentially is fetch your data, the categories (note that the component is an `async` component), and displays them as a list.
On top of the list, you have your client component `AddCategoryForm` which could look like this:

```js
'use client';

import { addCategory } from 'actions';

export default function AddCategoryForm() {
  return (
    <form action={addCategory}>
      <input type="hidden" name="otherField" value="some value" />
      <label htmlFor="name">Add new</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" required/>
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

It's a simple form which calls an `action` upon submit. The action is a server action, an async function on the server side which could look like that:

```js
'use server';

import { PrismaClient, Category } from "@prisma/client";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

export async function addCategory(formData: FormData) {
  try {
    const name: string = formData.get('name') as string;
    const otherField: string = formData.get('otherField') as string;

    const prisma: PrismaClient = new PrismaClient();
    const _category: Category = await prisma.category.create({
      data: {
        name,
        otherField,
      },
    });
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(error.message ?? 'An unexpected error occurred');
  } finally {
    revalidatePath('/categories');
  }
}
```

What it does is get the serialized data that has been sent through the form, use it to create your new category. At the end of the process, call the `revalidatePath` function to revalidate your `/categories` **url**. This will trigger the page.tsx component to refetch the categories (`await getCategories()`), and re-render an updated list of categories.

**Side note**:
If the page you need to revalidate has a dynamic segment in it, for example if you have something like:

```
/app
  domain/
    [domainId]
      categories/
        page.tsx
```

you would need to revalidate the path of the files instead with `'page'` as a second parameter like so:
`revalidatePath('/domain/[domainId]/categories', 'page');`

Comment: yes man, revalidatePath works for me. Thank you for advice!